# How to login to webpage with Python requests?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I'm trying to write script that login to website and monitor it's contetnt. I want to do this with requests, but despite status code 200, when I'm trying to get content or text after post, it showing me login page html code.
Code here:

```
import requests

POST_LOGIN_URL = 'https://app.distill.io/login'

REQUEST_URL = 'https://app.distill.io/watchlist#inbox'

payload = {
    'name': 'username',
    'password': 'pass'
}

h = {
    'referer': 'https://app.distill.io/watchlist#inbox',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36',
    }

h1 = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.session()
p = session.get(POST_LOGIN_URL)
cookies = dict(p.cookies)
p = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers=h, cookies=cookies)
print(p.status_code)
r = session.get(REQUEST_URL, headers=h1)
print(r.text)
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are you actually passing all required input fields to the login URL?

Comment: I think so, there are only 2 inputs in form tag.